Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python | Problem using interrupt
I have the following Arduino code that reads motor encoder data on Arduino interrupt pin2 and pin3 and publishes encoder ticks on the topic encoder1_ticks
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
//#include <std_msgs/String.h>
ros::NodeHandle nh;
std_msgs::Int32 encoder1_msgs;
ros::Publisher encoder1_msg("encoder1_ticks", &encoder1_msgs);


const int encoderPinA = 2; // Encoder channel A connected to pin 2
const int encoderPinB = 3; // Encoder channel B connected to pin 3

volatile long encoderTicks = 0;
volatile bool aSetLast = false;
volatile bool bSetLast = false;

void setup() {
//  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(encoderPinA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(encoderPinB, INPUT_PULLUP);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPinA), updateEncoder, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPinB), updateEncoder, CHANGE);

  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(encoder1_msg);
}

void loop() {
//  Serial.println(encoderTicks);
  delay(100);
}

void updateEncoder() {
  bool aSet = digitalRead(encoderPinA) == HIGH;
  bool bSet = digitalRead(encoderPinB) == HIGH;

  if (aSet != aSetLast || bSet != bSetLast) {
    if (aSet == bSetLast) {
      encoderTicks++;
    } else {
      encoderTicks--;
    }
    aSetLast = aSet;
    bSetLast = bSet;
  }

  encoder1_msg.publish(&encoder1_msgs);
  nh.spinOnce();
}

after uploading when I run rosrun rosserial_arduino serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0  get the following error on terminal
[INFO] [1712773059.264657]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1712773059.273464]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [1712773061.384046]: Requesting topics...
[ERROR] [1712773076.388195]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
[INFO] [1712773076.392705]: Requesting topics...
[ERROR] [1712773091.398718]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino

```

